# how to 'redirect' with react after login with passport.js?

Tags: reactjs, express, passport.js

Newbie react question: I’m using it with passport.js and express. I’m successfully logging in to the application. But I don't know how to do a redirect.

```
router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    res.redirect('/upload'); //<—— what I’d like to do is some kind of redirect here
});
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: you do that on the client

Comment: You probably use ajax request and for that don't use res.redirect instead use res.json({redirectURI: "/upload"}) and then in client handle response of ajax request - get redirectURI and basically write window.location = response.redirectURI

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense to me now, I'll give it a go, thanks.

Comment: What's the response you get on unsuccessful redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do that on your callback route.

```
router.get('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['public_profile', 'email'] }));

router.get('/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: "/" }), function (req, res) {
        if (req.user || req.session.user)
            return res.redirect('/' + req.user._id || req.session.user._id);
        return res.redirect('/login');
    });
```

Here, I have used `passport.js` for Facebook Login. and in `/facebook/callback` I have redirected to `/login` and in `/login` I have a function to check if the session is set.

```
if (Helper.isLoggedIn(req)) {
    res.redirect('/');
    return;
}
```

Definition of `isLoggedIn` inside `Helper.js` is

```
function isLoggedIn(req) {
    if (req.session && req.session.user_email && req.session.user_email != null) {
        if (!req.user || req.session.user == undefined || req.session.user == null) {
            loadUserFrom(req);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong in saying this but res.redirect does not appear to work with react.

Comment: It is working on my end. I am using react as well. There might me some other problem then.

Comment: So mike’s solution is working for me. I’m marking your solution as correct as I’m sure it must be if it’s working for you. To be honest it's only a toy project to introduce myself to react, so I’ll have to figure out the ins an outs of it. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

May be you can consider to do the redirect in react-js after the getting the response from server. Assume you use the redux-thunk.

action.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

export function signinUser({ email, password }) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/signin`, { email, password })
      .then(response => { 
        // Successful login, redirect to /upload
        browserHistory.push('/upload');

      })
      .catch(() => {
        //handle the error response from server

      });
  }
}
```