# React with Express Private Routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I've mainly been using server-side rendering solutions to pass data from the server to the client and render that in the browser.

Some major benefits to this include being able to get data and pass it to the client without exposing a route that is public. So being able to keep that data hidden and only expose it when I want. I know other applications such as Facebook have data that is able to be received ONLY by their applications (iOS, Android, web applications) for example timeline data is not a public route and is only able to be received by their own applications.

How can I achieve something like this using React? With server-side rendering I can lock down those functions/routes and only allow them to be called from the backend code and not expose them, I can also do things like check to make sure the user is logged in and such.

How can I achieve this with React?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely. Do you want to restrict access to part/all of your api to your authorized app, or do you want to hide that api behind some kind of "wall" inaccessible from outside of your servers?

Comment: @SrThompson Both kinda. Some routes I want only logged in users to access. And some routes I want to be behind a wall that only my servers/apps can access. And some I want both.

Comment: You'll most likely have to architect your system into separate services. To ensure that only your react app (or any other client that you authorize) can access your routes, you can implement oauth2. In the client side it's trivial to restrict routes only to authenticated users if you're using something like react-router. Internal communication between services is trickier if you really want to hide the routes and depends on your env.,  you could use a message queue (e.g. RabbitMQ) or have your services in the same physical server... (disclaimer: I've never implemented such a system)

Comment: SrThompson is onto the right solution. Do you really want to provide complete example code to a would-be hacker on how your admin/restricted services work? Why not just deploy a couple different builds of the same "full" application and just exclude the parts you don't need. If it runs on the client, if it makes makes decisions then ***it is available to the client side*** Obviously you can still do server side filtering of the data (security) and reflect a state based on that. React runs in the browser. Your back-end runs on the server. Secure the back end and the client is fine.

Comment: @DanielB.Chapman So I kinda understand what you are saying. I mean anything that is available to the client can be viewed and hacked or accessed almost. In like mobile development that stuff is more restricted and it's easier to protect things since it's a binary. But I'm still confused about how I could protect those routes. Like if I have different builds, one for public routes and one for private. Who's to say that someone can't just hit the private build? It's almost like I want a key or token to say that the HTTP request is coming from my app and my app only.

Comment: @CharlieFish there's no perfect security. If you want to filter from the app why note just create a route that has a `key/signature/whatever` from your app. Someone can almost certainly spoof it so don't rely on it. It sounds like you're concerned about security: use OAuth or some other form to secure the data on the server and you'll be fine. React doesn't really have "routes" it is a client side framework. Your server has routes so secure it there.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you want to restrict certain routes to logged in users.

For logging in with an identity provider like Facebook, the goto is passport.js. A question about using react/express/passport has been asked before on SO, eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41938366/3518108).

Edits in response to comments:

So, you have some functions that output data. If you render server side, those functions aren't exposed. But, if you expose them via an API... They are exposed. And since the JavaScript code gets sent to the client, you can't just put a secret in a header, because you have to send that secret to the client.

What I was saying above is, if you restrict those APIs to **logged in** users, then the problem is solved by OAuth and/or JWTs, a la [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/securing-node-js-restful-apis-with-json-web-tokens-9f811a92bb52). JWTs coukd also work for you without login.

However, if what you want to do is leave the API open to requests from your app, whether or not the user is logged in, I don't know any perfect solution, just some tricks:

- Use HTTPS
- Set CORS policies to only allow your domain(s)
- Use a package like [Helmet](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet)

Another thing worth checking out that I haven't used, but looks good is [Microgateway](https://github.com/strongloop/microgateway/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Not really. I mean that is part of it. But I've figured that out. An example is this. Imagine I have a weather app. With server side rendering I can have a Javascript function that gets the weather data, then passes that data through the server side rendering. That Javascript function that gets the data can ONLY be used by my application. Ensuring only my application can use it. With React or client side things I would need to expose a route. So any application can send a request and get data back. I'm trying to figure out how to ensure that ONLY my app can do that. Like server side rendering.

Comment: Charlie, I edited my answer in response to your comments. Does it now address what you're talking about?

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly solved using the different concepts of authentication / authorisation, as for example defined in the OAuth2 Protocol.

Let me describe this on a very high and abstract level:

You can say that there are different clients that access your API. The API can define which client can access which route.
Each client has a client ID and a client secret to identify themselves to an authentication server, and to exchange the ID and secret against a token. This token (Json Web Token for example) encodes the permissions for this client, which could for instance mean to access certain routes, and not others, in your API.

However you have to consider that no pure web application is 100% safe, i.e. there are no means by which the client secret mentioned above can be protected with 100% certainty in a pure web application. For that purpose, you should also implement another authentication flow using passwords etc...  Otherwise, you will also have to implement some sort of server-side proxy that keeps the secret safe on the server-side, and gets the token returned to the client.

If you use a 3rd party API where you want to restrict access to, you will need to put a proxy or API Gateway in between, which will perform the access control as described above. So this means that the routes that can be accessed in this manner shouldn't expore any sensitive data such as user data.

I hope these thoughts help you in some way to find the right architecture for your problem..